# Django form not submitting data

Tags: python-3.x, django

I'm making a simple to do list app. I have a form that is not submitting upon clicking submit.
When I click submit the following url appears:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/update_task/1/?  csrfmiddlewaretoken=k8tpRlypuPUsckyGE4sekciegDUl0ghBqxelylScAUiZJeEs3AOnYWO1K6HATTgC&title=Go+shopping%28Updated%29&complete=on&Update+Task=Submit

Here is my code:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Task
from .forms import TaskForm


def index(request):
    tasks = Task.objects.all()

    form = TaskForm()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('/')

    context = {'tasks':tasks, 'form':form}
    return render(request, 'task/list.html', context)


def updateTask(request, pk):
    task = Task.objects.get(id=pk)

    form = TaskForm(instance=task)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TaskForm(request.POST, instance=task)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'task/update_task.html', context)
```

update_task.html

```
<h5>Update Task</h5>

<form class="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <input type="submit" name='Update Task'>
</form>
```

list.html

```
<h2>To Do</h2>

<div class="center-column">
    <form method="POST" action="/">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.title}}
        <input type="submit" name="Create Task">
    </form>

    <div class="todo-list">

        {% for task in tasks %}
            <div class="item-row">
                <a href="{% url 'update_task' task.id %}">Update</a>
            
                {% if task.complete == True %}
                <strike>{{task}}</strike>
                {% else %}
                <span>{{task}}</span>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

task/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='list'),
    path('update_task/<str:pk>/', views.updateTask, name='update_task'),

]
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Correct in `update_task.html`. Here add `method='POST'`

Comment: In your `update_task.html` you are adding `class="POST"`, replace it with `method="POST"`

Comment: I don't know how I missed that. Thank you so much.